# bonsai kafka unable to connect from apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am trying to connect to bonsai kafka clustur from apche camel springboot app .

Below is my config (password changed)

```
camel.component.kafka.brokers=https://321312:213213@camel-4054112539.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net:443
camel.component.kafka.security-protocol=SSL
camel.component.kafka.ssl-truststore-location=C:/Users/meow/tools/jdk1.8.0_291/jre/lib/security/cacerts
camel.component.kafka.ssl-truststore-password=changeit
```

Below is producer

```
 public class ActiveSenderRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:kafka-timer?period=5000").bean(MessageCreater.class).to("kafka:mytopic");

    }
}

@Component
class MessageCreater {
    int i = 0;

    public void createMessage(Exchange ex) {
        String message = "my message " + (++i);
        System.out.println("writing to log");
        ex.getIn().setBody(message);
    }
}
```

I am getting below error  , the first line contiues for long and then getting log from second line

> 2021-06-24 16:27:01.367  WARN 13456 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker camel-4054112539.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

> 2021-06-24 16:35:07.997  WARN 9112 --- [ad | producer-1]
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer
> clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker
> camel-4054112539.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net:443 (id: -1 rack: null)
> disconnected 2021-06-24 16:35:08.163 ERROR 9112 --- [r://kafka-timer]
> o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for
> (MessageId: 4ACC1A23B54E627-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId:
> 4ACC1A23B54E627-0000000000000000). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1
> caught: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic mytopic
> not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
>
> Message History (complete message history is disabled)
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor
> Elapsed (ms) [route1            ] [route1            ]
> [from[timer://kafka-timer?period=5000]
> ] [     60054]    ... [route1            ] [to1               ]
> [kafka:mytopic
> ] [         0]
>
> ### Stacktrace
>
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic mytopic not
> present in metadata after 60000 ms.
>
> 2021-06-24 16:35:08.167  WARN 9112 --- [r://kafka-timer]
> o.a.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer  : Error processing exchange.
> Exchange[4ACC1A23B54E627-0000000000000000]. Caused by:
> [org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException - Topic mytopic not
> present in metadata after 60000 ms.]
>
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic mytopic not
> present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems on your kafka broker the automatic creation of topic is not enabled, so you need to create mytopic topic first and then run the route, or enabling the automatic creation of topic.